# Recurrence Equation Simplification

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, recurrence

Given a pseudocode like this:

```
int algorithm(int[] a, i, j)
    if i > j
        return 0

    int n = j - i + 1
    int d = n / 4

    algorithm(a, i, i+3d-1)
    algorithm(a, i+d, j)

    return 1
```

The main cost is the cost given by the two recursive calls. The dimension of this two recursive calls should be in my opinion: **3n/4** for the first one (ignoring the 1) and **n/4** for the second one. This means:

**T(n) = T(3n/4) + T(n/4) + O(1)**

- **Question 1:** is this correct?
- **Question 2:** is `T(n) = 2T(3n/4) + O(1)` correct?

Comment: From T(n) = T(3n/4) + T(n/4) + O(1) and the fact that T is an increasing function, you can conclude T(n) ≤ 2 T(3n/4) + O(1). Note the ≤ sign. You can also conclude T(n) ≥ 2 T(n/4) + O(1).

Comment: But still to be precise if we use the second one we can use the Master Theorem and state that T(n)=O(n^(log(4/3),2) not theta of this. I mean: T(n)<=2 T(3n/4) + O(1)= theta(n^(log(4/3),2) and so T(n)=O(...).

Comment: I suspect a typo (`int d= m/4`). Please check.

Comment: How do you justify the `T(n/4)` ??

Comment: In the function prototype, `n` should be `a`. Pay attention to details.

Comment: The first recursive call has n=3*d and d has dimension equal to 1/4 of the input then n=3*n/4, whereas on the second one n=d=n/4.

Comment: Presumably you are answering me. Why `n=d` ?

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the variables `i` and `j` are redundant because only their difference is used. So we can substitute `j-i+1` with `n` everywhere. We can also ignore the argument `a` for clarity. The code becomes

```
int algorithm(n)
    if 1>n
         return 0
    int d= n/4
    algorithm(3d)
    algorithm(n-1-d)
    return 1
```

Next transformation: substitute `d`. We can also discard the returned value !

```
algorithm(n)
    if 1>n
         return
    algorithm(3(n/4))
    algorithm(n-1-n/4)
```

Comment: This is correct and i agree that the algorithm was not well written but it was to erase all the useless details of the actual algorithm, the core of the question was which was the corresponding recurrence equation.

Comment: @ScooterzGiovanni: you don't realize that this gives you the solution in a neat way ! It is not purist "cleanup" but rigorous program transformation. It shows your mistake.